# To split the given strings into integers and characters in C language

Tags: c

For example my input is : 19A70 how can I split it into 19 A 70. By using atoi() func i can only split the first integer 19 and i can't split the other two elements
help needed guys!

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: You can't do this just using atoi, I don't think. strol will give you an end pointer where it stops parsing, but I think you'd do better splitting the string up yourself first by scanning it and testing each character with isdigit() etc.

Comment: Are you asking in general or do you have a specific format in mid? In other words, can the string be any combination of digits and non-digits or do you always have a number, then some letters, then a number?

Comment: if i do that i would split it as 1 9 A 7 0 but my needed output is 19 A 70

Comment: You may want to do a bit of coding. Start with `char* p = "19A70" `, then use `isdigit(*p)` ( and possibly `isalpha(*p)` ) to distinguish between digits and other characters. PS. C is fairly low-level, be prepared to code a lot yourself. [PPS. Here's a good C tutorial, btw](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/)

Comment: Is 19A70 a string or a simple input into the console?

Comment: Your question is unfortunately missing a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example.

Comment: Avoid use of `atoi()` it has *zero* error-detection and will silently return `0` if given `atoi("my cow");` and you will be unaware of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> *"For example my input is : 19A70. How can I split it into 19 A 70."*

It is not quite clear to me if you need to parse and split a proper string (as the question title said) or you just want the input to be in different entities according to their type and thereafter print them (as you said you have your input as `19A70`).

If it is the first, I`ll delete this answer and use [Clifford´s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61269394/12139179) or [Charlie´s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61269734/12139179) approach in the other answers.

If it is the latter, just use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a,c;
   char b;

   if(scanf("%d%c%d",&a,&b,&c) != 3)
   {
       fprintf(stderr,"Error at scanning!");
       return 1;
   }

   printf("%d %c %d",a,b,c);
}
```

Execution:

```
/a.out
19A70
19 A 70
```

Comment: Or even make `char [128]` and then `"%d%127[^0-9]%d"`. (in case you have `"19APPLES70"`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strspn()` and `strcspn()` for this:

```c
#include <string.h>

void split_string(const char *s) {
    int len1, len2;
    for (;;) {
        /* count the number of digits */
        len1 = strspn(s, "0123456789");
        if (len1) {
            printf(" %.*s", len1, s);
        }
        s += len1;
        /* count the number of letters */
        len2 = strspn(s, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
        if (len2) {
            printf(" %.*s", len2, s);
        }
        s += len2;
        /* if neither digits nor letters found: stop */
        if (len1 + len2 == 0)
            break;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: @user3121023: of course :) thank you David for correcting my post. Actually I only use `strspn`, but if the goal is to separate digits and non-digits, `strcspn` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

If the format is fixed and guaranteed to be as you have specified, then `sscanf()` may be appropriate:

```
char test[] = "19A70" ;
int a = 0 ;
int b = 0 ;
char c ;

int check = sscanf( test, "%d%c%d", &a, &c, &b ) ;    
if( check == 3 )
{
    printf( "%d %d %c\n", a, b, c ) ;
}
else
{
    printf( "Parse failed\n" ) ;
}
```

`sscanf()` provides limited scope for validation, but if the data is machine generated or previously validated that is not really an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had fun solving this problem. I present my solution here.

The implemented code recognizes numbers of `double` type and strings parsing an input string.

There is a problem still to solve, when the `-` is in the middle of the input string and is not followed by a number, but by the decimal separator `.` the program associates the `-` to a string.

Warning: The function `strtod`, used in the code, interpretes as HEX numbers the pieces of string starting with `0x` and translates it in decimal numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[200];
    char b[200];
    char * x, * y;
    int i=0;
    double v=0;

    printf("Hit only <enter> to stop\n\n");
    do {
        printf("Insert a string: ");
        fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin);
        a[strlen(a)-1]=0; // Removes the \n at the end

            if (a[0]) {
// ----------------- Start parsing   
            x=a;
            do {
                v=strtod(x,&y); // get a number
// Warning strtod translates number starting with 0x from HEX
                if (x!=y)
                    printf("[%f] ",v);

                if (y!=NULL && *y) { 
                    i=0;x=y; // get a string
                    while(*x && !isdigit(*x)
                           && !(*x=='-' && isdigit(*(x+1))) // negative number
                           && !(*x=='.' && isdigit(*(x+1))) // decimal number
                         //&& !(case -.{digit}) is not managed!!
                           )
                        b[i++]=*x++;

                    if (i) {
                        b[i]=0;
                        printf("[%s] ",b);
                    }
                }
            } while(y!=NULL && *y);
        }
        puts("");
// ----------------- End parsing   

    } while(a[0]!=0);

    return 0;
}
```